# Mining XML documents by Apriori algorithm

Tags: xml, xquery, data-mining, apriori

I’m trying to mine association rules from XML documents by Apriori algorithm. Doing so, there are two general approaches: 1) mapping XML to relational format and applying classical Apriori, 2) mining XML directly. I’d like to use the latter one but there are several problems.

After researching, I’ve found two incomplete solutions:

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917638/finding-1-itemset-2-itemset-n-itemset-from-xml-document) in SO that provides solution for generating k-itemset

This [paper](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/30384902/10.1.1.6.1017-libre.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ56TQJRTWSMTNPEA&Expires=1421105653&Signature=3kjOiis3yY3Jomy6dXoYfdAcF7U%3D) that proposes a simulation of Apriori by XQuery (the provided code is not complete)

Please let me know your ideas and suggestions on how I can do that (for both approaches)?

**Update:**

According to another version of the mentioned paper, the data set is something like this:

```
<transactions>
<transaction id="1">
 <items>
<item>a</item> 
<item>d</item>
<item>e</item>
 </items>
</transaction>

<transaction id="2">
 <items>
<item>b</item> 
<item>c</item>
<item>d</item>
 </items>
</transaction>

<transaction id="3">
 <items>
<item>a</item> 
<item>c</item>
 </items>
</transaction>

<transaction id="4">
 <items>
<item>b</item> 
<item>c</item>
<item>d</item>
 </items>
</transaction>

<transaction id="5">
 <items>
<item>a</item> 
<item>b</item>
 </items>
</transaction>

</transactions>
```

Then, the functions are as follows

```
define function join(element $X, element $Y) returns element {
let $items := (for $item in $Y
where every $i in $X satisfies
$i != $item
return $item)
return $X union $items
}

define function commonIts(element $X, element $Y) returns
element {
for $item in $X
where some $i in $Y satisfies $i = $item
return $item
}

define function removeIts(element $X, element $Y) returns
element {
for $item in $X
where every $i in $Y satisfies $i != $item
return $item
}

define function candidateGen(element $l) returns element {
for $freqSet1 in $l
let $items1 := $freqSet1//items/*
for $freqSet2 in $l
let $items2 := $freqSet2//items/*
where $freqSet2 >> $freqSet1 and
count($items1)+1 =  count($items1 union $items2)
and prune(join($items1,$items2), $l)
return <items>
{join($items1,$items2)}
</items>
}

define function prune(element $X, element $Y) returns boolean
{
every $item in $X satisfies
some $items in $Y//items satisfies
count(commonIts(removeIts($X,$item),$items/*))
= count($X) - 1
}

define function removeDuplicate(element $C) returns element
{
for $itemset1 in $C
let $items1 := $itemset1/*
let $items :=(for $itemset2 in $C
let $items2 := $itemset2/*
where $itemset2>>$itemset1 and
count($items1) =
count(commonIts($items1, $items2))
return $items2)
where count($items) = 0
return $itemset1
}

define function getLargeItemsets(element $C, element $minsup,
element $total, element $src) returns element {
for $items in $C
let $trans := (for $tran in $src
where every $item1 in $items/* satisfies
some $item2 in $tran/*
satisfies $item1 = $item2
return $tran)
let $sup := (count($trans) * 1.00) div $total
where $sup >= $minsup
return <largeItemset> {$items}
<support> {$sup} </support>
</largeItemset>
}

define function apriori(element $l, element $L, element $minsup,
element $total, element $src) returns element {
let $C := removeDuplicate(candidateGen($l))
let $l := getLargeItemsets($C, $minsup, $total, $src)
let $L := $l union $L
return if (empty($l)) then
$L
else
apriori($l, $L, $minsup, $total, $src)
}

let $src := document(“/transactions.xml”)//items
let $minsup := 0.4
let $items := (for $item in $src/*
where $itemset = $item
let $total := count($src) * 1.00
let $C := distinct-values($src/*)
let $l :=(for $itemset in $C
return $item)
let $sup := (count($items) * 1.00) div $total
where $sup >= $minsup
return <largeItemset>
<items> {$itemset} </items>
<support> {$sup} </support>
</largeItemset>)
let $L := $l
return <largeItemsets> { apriori($l, $L,$minsup, $total, $src) }
</largeItemsets>
```

and to compute rule documents, they introduced this expression:

```
let $minconf := 1.00
let $src := document(“/large.xml”)//largeItemset
for $itemset1 in $src
let $items1 := $itemset1/items/*
for $itemset2 in $src
let $items2 := $itemset2/items/*
where count($items1) > count($items2) and
count(commonIts($items1, $items2)) =
count($items2) and $itemset1/support div
$itemset2/support >= $minconf
return <rule support =“{$itemset1/support}”
confidence = “{($itemset1/support*1.0) div
($itemset2/support*1.0)}”>
<antecedent> {$items2} </antecedent>
<consequent>
{removeItems($items1,$items2)}
</consequent>
</rule>
```

Now, the big challenge for me is to integrate these functions together to work.

Comment: Unfortunately your question isn't a good fit for SO, as it mainly asks for the complete code for some algorithmic problem. I would suggest you try for yourself using XQuery to write this algorithm and you come back with specific questions if you fail to "integrate these functions together", as you said yourself.

Comment: I'm working on, however since I'm new in XQuery, it's a bit confusing and complicated to me to find out different portions and details of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach will be a lot faster. Preprocess the data only *once* (processing XML is quite costly), into an input format well suited for your algorithm!

Questions about finding source code are off-topic here. Try to solve the problem,  come back with specific questions that involve code you've written, and try to present them in a concise format so they can be well answered in a self-contained QA style.

Also note that above attempt at implementing Apriori with Xquery lacks some of the *essential* optimizations that make up the contribution of the Apriori algorithm. For a really useable Apriori implementation, you *will* need to use optimized data structures, you cannot achieve this in XQuery. Try running this implementation on some of the classic data sets, and it will just *die*. Getting Apriori to scale is hard enough, but doing it with XQuery is the road to madness - a key challenge is to keep the memory usage low, even in C!

Comment: Your answer seems to be mainly a comment, rather than an actual answer. Only your first two sentences somewhat answer the question and by itself wouldn't be enough for a quality answer. Simply stating that one approach is a lot faster is not really helpful - _why_ is it faster?

Comment: Also, your answer that the first approach would be faster is simply incorrect. You can implement an a priori algorithm as well in e.g. XQuery and use XML as data source.

Comment: Processing XML *repeatedly* is costly. You only want to do it once. That is why it's faster. You seem to advocate XQuery, but have you every implemented APRIORI? (Also note that the question was edited after my answer...)

Comment: true, repeatedly processing XML is costly, but there are several native XML databases out there (eXist, BaseX, ...) who only process it once and then hold it in a processing-efficient format in main-memory. Implementing this problem in XQuery has the same difficulties as in every other functional languages such as Haskell. Also, I do not advocate XQuery, I just use it every day and therefore am quite familiar with its possibilities and restrictions.

Comment: In the mentioned paper, it is stated that implementation with high level programming languages (specifically C++) is faster than XQuery implementation of same algorithm.